# how to add and import multipart library in android studio

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to add multipart entity library in my project
Please show me a way that how can I download library and add, import  to android studio 1.2.2.0
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering too late maybe, but I faced the problem today and didn't find good responses. So maybe this might still help. Also this is my first answer in SO.

1. So to use Multipart library in Android Studio, you can download **httpcomponents-client-4.x** from [Apache site](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and put **httpcore-4.x.jar** and **httpmime-4.x.jar** in **libs** folder of project directory. And update **build.gradle** file as -

   ```
   android {
       ....
       packagingOptions {
           exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
           exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
           exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
           exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
           exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
       }
       ....
   }
   ```

   And in the dependencies add-

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       ...
       compile files('libs/httpcore-4.x.jar')
       compile files('libs/httpmime-4.x.jar')
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Or you can add from maven repository by adding library names like-

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       ...
       compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1"
       compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6"
       ...
   }
   ```

**Note**: You can modify **build.gradle** of app module directly or you can add from **module setting** pressing **F4** and then in **Dependencies** tab with '**+**' button and select the **File dependency** for option 1, **Library dependency** for option 2.